# ASP.NET Performance, 100 "Memory Hard Faults" indiciate a memory swapping problem?

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, iis-7

With a customer web site we currently experiences performance problems.

While analyzing the problem we found an unexpected amount of of 112 "Memory Hard Faults" per minute. Does anybody can interpret the meaning of this value? Does this happen, when memory swapping is necessary - so the root cause is not sufficient memory?

Even if the CPU value seems high, it is not the main problem for the slow web site. Do you agree?

[image]

To see the processor time:

[image]

We will separate the SQL-Server and Webserver very soon.

Comment: @Robert, witch way and version you read and write on sql ? eg using subsonic,linq, ado ?

Comment: NHibernate, but this is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a working set of nearly 4GB for w3wp.exe. Yes, this sounds like you've got a memory problem.

That doesn't necessarily mean that you just haven't got enough memory though - my guess is that you've got a leak somewhere. That amount of CPU usage is disturbingly high too. How much of the processor is being used by the web site?

Also, it looks like the database and the web site are being run on the same host - are you able to separate them?

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows the average processor time (50% IIS and 13% Sql-Server). We will separate the sql-sever soon. This will also free some memory resources and should be an interim solution until we get (hopefully) some more traffic. I am still puzzled about "Memory Hard Faults" since I never noticed something like that before.

Comment: That 50% IIS - is this a dual processor box? If so, that could be a whole processor pegged by one thread.

Comment: No the 50% is just coincidence.

Comment: Indeed the problem is a memory-leak, CPU is only a minor issues, thank you for your insights!